# Unity 3d | Gravity scale value varies for different device resolutions. So gameobject not reaching to specified height for all devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame-rate, screen-resolution, gravity, pixel-density

I am developing a 2D game where i throw a gameobject vertically upword direction using AddForce api. Now as the gameobject start moving upword due to force applied, i keep on increasing its gravity scale from 1 to specific value (say maxGravityScaleValue )in Update(). Once maxGravityScaleValue is reached, ball falls down. I developed game using reference resolution of 1080x1920. For this reference resolution maxGravityScaleValue was 960 (i just fond it out by trial and error).So i thought it will be consistent for all devices.However later when i tried my game on various mobile devices the maxGravityScaleValue was varying inconsistently for different devices. I am sure For every device unity is doing some calculation to determine that max gravity scale value. I tried many calculation but no luck. Please help me to come out of this situation

As the gameobject has to go vertically upword and fall under gravity after reaching specific height, i will give Y coordinate of gameobject, height and maxGravityScaleValue for different resolutions.

1. Resolution :1080x1920 (aspect ratio 9:16) , maxGravityScaleValue :960, gameObjectY : 375 TargetY : 1440
2. Resolution :1080x2280 (aspect ratio 9:19) , maxGravityScaleValue :1440, gameObjectY : 555 TargetY : 1620
3. Resolution :1125x2436 (aspect ratio 9:19.5) , maxGravityScaleValue :1200, gameObjectY : 608.62 TargetY : 1718
4. Resolution :1242x2688 (aspect ratio 9:19.5) , maxGravityScaleValue :1030, gameObjectY : 671.25 TargetY : 1896
5. Resolution :1440x2560 (aspect ratio 9:16) , maxGravityScaleValue :850, gameObjectY : 500 TargetY : 1920

Game Object thrown vertically upword using AddForce. Should fall down after reaching  TargetY. My logic is to increase gravity scale from 1 to maxValue when force is applied. So once maxGravity value is reached, Gameobject should be at TargetY and from there it should fall under down.

Comment: I have a couple of questions:

Why are you adjusting the gravity scale when you can use the Rigidbody2D?

Are you adjusting your camera in anyway to account for the difference in Resolution?

Comment: @CardCastleStudio Thanks for your comment. 
1) I am using rigidbody2D as well. 2) I am not adjusting camera for different resolutions. I am new to unity 3d If i am doing anything wrong please let me know.

Comment: Its a simple 2d game where in i am throwing a ball placed on ground towards hoop. So i want ball not to go above hoop. So there  is targetY up to which ball should go

Comment: Essentially what is happening, your camera is changing resolution which results in the object looking like it is going higher than it should. This is due to the number of Units that are being displayed within the view of the Camera. I would recommend changing the size of the camera, Orthographic / Perspective, with a simple script that checks the current resolutions of the screen in the Start(). This will allow you to keep every other variable the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I tried your solution but no luck. Later I changed Update() to FixedUpdate(). It simplified my calculations.